# Android fixed RTL and LTR orientation

Tags: android, user-interface, right-to-left, left-to-right

Hi Im building an app in my native language which is rtl orientation Is there a way to make all supported devices to show the same UI not depending on ltr or rtl orientation?

Answer (score 0):

RTL support was introduced in Android 4.2 (API 17).  You can specify `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` for all top layouts of your app. By default, it will be inherited by all child layouts and views.